# Can you build only one road using road building development card in Catan?

Tags: catan

If you play the road building development card in Catan, can you build only one road? Does the answer change if the reason is:

1. You don't have enough roads available?
2. There is only one valid place for you to build a road?
3. You just don't want to build two roads for some reason?

Comment: I think in the video game I play you have to build two unless you can't because you've run out of roads (but you don't have to build two if you can't; it lets me build just one). I don't know about what happens when there's nowhere to build a road, but I would assume it would let you built just one.